# Can you git interactive rebase squash after having merged development into my feature branch previously?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, rebase, interactive, squash

As title says, can I interactive rebase my commits and squash them after I merged the newest shared development into my local feature branch? I tend to often merge dev so I don't have too many conflicts at the end of my feature. I want to keep my features to 2-3 commits and not have to make use of stash as often as I do now. Feels safer if I could commit more often, then clean up right before pushing.

Side question: What's the best way to squash merge commits? Fiddled around with merge --squash today but then I'll still have to make a commit, and I'm back at the original question - whether rebase -i to squash is permitted in that case.

Comment: IMHO when on feature branch, rebasing the develop branch is cleaner than merging specifically because of this problem: all your work is by default ahead of the commits on `dev`, and you don't have all those merge commits cluttering your branch's history. (But that probably doesn't help you solve your present problem).

Comment: Yeah now that I think about it you're right tbh. Simply rebasing instead of merging and jumping through hoops sounds like it's supposed to do exactly what I'm looking for. Anyways, thanks, I'll experiment with this on a test repo for sure